# Passing objects to Custom Control Structures in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I can't call member functions on objects that I pass to custom control structures in Laravel 4.1.23.

My custom control structure:

```
Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler){
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('paginatePretty');
    $code = 
        '$1<?php
        echo $2->getCurrentPage();
        ?>';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $code, $view);
});
```

My blade view code that instantiates paginatePretty:

```
// $articles = Articles::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate($per_page);
@paginatePretty($articles)
```

At compile time, I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ';'
```

And the custom control structure was compiled like this:

```
echo ($articles)->getCurrentPage();
```

How can I pass an object to the custom control structure?

Answer (score 0):

Use `list()` and `array` to solve:

```
Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler){
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('paginatePretty');
    $code = 
        '$1<?php
        #echo $2->getCurrentPage();  --> the bad code
        list($_paginator) = array$2;
        echo $_paginator->getCurrentPage();
    ?>';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $code, $view);
});
```

I prefix variables declared inside of custom control structures with an underscore to avoid collisions in the view.